# Usar $_POST em um variável em Php

Tags: php, post

estou aprendendo a utilizar `POO` gostaria de pedir uma ajuda, pois não consigo inserir o `$_POST` dentro de uma variável, já pesquisei e olhei meus livros, mas não estou conseguindo ter evolução . Fico agradecido pela ajuda em aprender isso da forma correta.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['enviarFrech'])) {
    $fech = $_POST['st'];
    $data_atual = date("Y-m-d");
    print_r($fech);
    echo $data_atual;

    class DadosMontagem {

        public $lojamont;
        public $monta;

        public function set_lojamontador($l) {
            $this->$lojamont = $l;
        }

        public function lsmt() {
            echo $l;
        }

    }

    $ls_mt = new DadosMontagem($_POST['lojamontar']);
    $ls_mt->set_lojamontador();
    $ls_mt->lsmt();
    fechamentoMontador($conexao, $fech, $ls, $mt, $data_atual);
}
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi o problema.

Comment: Aparentemente você está utilizando certo, a questão é se está fazendo o envio corretamente...para sabermos isso precisa postar o formulário que está enviando os dados.

Comment: Vc está passando os dados do formulário como " method='post' "?

Comment: Sim. Estou enviando via method='post' fiz um echo antes da classe e exibi   os dados corretament, porém dentro da classe faço errado, ainda estou aprendendo a utilizar POO então tenho certeza que cometi erros bobos de um iniciante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos separar por etapas:

- **Organização**: sugiro que declare o escopo da classe primeiro, para somente então trabalhar no escopo fora da mesma. Essa abordagem deixa o código mais organizado.
- **Escopo/segurança**: declare os atributos como **private**, isso aumenta a segurança pois estes ficam visíveis somente no escopo da classe. Para alterar os atributos, pode chamar o *setNomeDoMetodo($argumento)*, isso permite que dentro do método você realize validações antes de alterar o atributo. Já para ler o atributo você utilizar o *getNomeDoMetodo()*
- **Nomes sugestivos**: declares os métodos e variáveis com nomes curtos, mas sugestivos. Essa abordagem fará com que você não se perca no código conforme ele cresce.

---

```
<?php

class DadosMontagem
{
    private $lojamont;
    private $monta;

    public function setLoja( $loja )
    {
            $this->lojamont = $loja;
    }

    public function getLoja()
    {
        return $this->lojamont;
    }
}

if(!empty($_POST['lojamontar']))
{
    $obj = new DadosMontagem;
    $obj->setLoja($_POST['lojamontar']);
    echo 'Data: ' . date("Y-m-d") . '<br>';
    echo 'Loja: ' . $obj->getLoja();
}
?>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="lojamontar" />
  <button type="submit">Salvar Dados</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Fabio não sei porque mas eu testei seu código e ele tem o mesmo comportamento que o que havia feito. Só executa o $_POST fora da objeto. Mas me foi util para melhorar minha forma de contrução de uma classe.

Comment: Adicionei um form para que veja o funcionamento e tome como exemplo.

Comment: Entendo realmente fiz alguns teste inclusive vindo de outro arquivo e funciona perfeitamente. Vou estudar mais, muito obrigado pelas suas dicas

Answer (score 1):

Cara,se não está passando é porque você deve estar errando no `method` do formulário. Não tem erro, segue essa lógica:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nome_post" />
  <button type="submit">Salvar Dados</button>
</form>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['nome_post'])){
  $post_ok = $_POST['nome_post'];
  echo $post_ok; //se imprimir é pq está passando corretamente
}
?>
```